# Versioned modal pop up one time per user

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage, bootstrap-modal

In my website, I want to display a modal everytime I update the "patch notes", meaning the new features and bug fixes. The updates and bug fixes are saved on another project database, so I'll need to call an API to get the content. The problem is that I can't think of a good solution on how to do this.

**What I thought of doing**

- Call the API to get the latest updates version
- Check if the user have this version of the update saved on his local storage
- If it has, doesn't display the modal because he already seen it
- If not, update or create the local storage and call the API to fill the modal with the correct content

My problem with this is that everytime the user logs in or go to the home page, I'll have to call the API.

Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks!